# Why is there no ActiveRecord REST adapter

Tags: rest, activerecord, activeresource

We've been working on various projects using ActiveResource for a couple years now. It seems that ActiveResource is great to use if you are using Rails on both the client and server sides.

**Problems with ActiveResource**

We're using Scala on the server side and constantly running up against "Oh, ActiveResource doesn't want the API to `<do this standard thing>`" or "ActiveResource does `<this weird thing>`" so we have to change the server to support the demands of the client. This has all been discussed before, I know.

Another problem is that many gems and libraries require ActiveRecord. I can't count the number of gems we've run into that "require" your model to use ActiveRecord even though they don't actually *use* the actual AR functionality. It seems this is mostly because that's the easy path for gem development. "I'm using ActiveRecord, and can't imagine anyone not using it, so I'll just require that rather than figure out the more general way" (note, I've done this myself, so I'm not simply complaining)

So, if we use ActiveResource, we have to break the server to make it work, and we can't use a large portion of what makes Rails great.

**REST Adapter?**

All of this brought us to ask the question "Why does ActiveResource exist at all?" I mean, why would you have this secondary data storage path? Why isn't ActiveResource just a REST adapter? With a REST adapter, you can have all the good things in all the gems, and don't have to fight with ActiveResource's finicky nature. You just build your model the same way you build *any* model.

So I started exploring building one. It actually doesn't seem difficult at all. A few hours work and you could have the basic functionality built up. There are examples elsewhere using REST and SOAP, so it's doable.

So the question comes back. *If it's so easy, why the hell hasn't this been done before?*

**Not simply a datastore?**

I've come up with what I wonder is the answer. While building up a scaffold for this, I quickly ran into an issue. REST is very good at doing two things: 1) Act on *this* object, and 2) Act on *all* objects. In fact, that's pretty much the limit of the REST standard.

And so I started to wonder if *scope* is the reason there's no REST adapter. The ActiveRecord subsystem seems to need more than just "get one" and "get all." It's based on *querying* the datastore as much as anything.

**The Actual Question**

So, the actual question: Is there no ActiveRecord REST adapter simply because REST defines no standardized way to say "give me all of the cars where the car is in the same parking lot as these drivers and the drivers have a key."

Answer (score 0):

That's right.

Unlike databases which have SQL as a standard way to express conditions, there is no standard in REST to support all the ActiveRecord functions, such as joins, group, and having.

How many hours work do you think it would take to do correlated queries or sub-queries?

---

I'm not being casually dismissive here.  This concept touches on some personal projects I've considered, with some of the same issues I've been thinking through.

ActiveRecord supports all of SQL, which is way more powerful than most people use or need.  Basically every part of an SQL statement has an ActiveRecord method which takes a string to fill in that section of the SQL.

You'd want to limit the client to the part of ActiveRecord people actually use.  You'd still need IS NULL, and IS NOT NULL.  You'd need comparisons such as less than and greater than.  You'd want to support OR statements, for "field1 IS NULL OR field1 = ''".

To do all the comparison stuff, like where(["updated_at > ?", cutoff]) you would need a RESTful server more robust than existing web services.  The server would have to use your gem, or be built with guidelines for implementing all the functionality.

So, in the end why?  You're implementing a limited database API, going over the network with string URLs instead of binary packets, to a database engine that you are implementing.

Comment: I understand; however, given that there are ActiveRecord ORMs built from RESTful services, these don't seem like insurmountable obstacles, just details and API documentation. Still, I understand more why this is not in core. It seems valuable and useful, but I probably wouldn't put it into core either, unless until some details you discuss in your other answer are worked out.

Comment: So, I guess you found ActiveRecord ORMs built from RESTful services.  Basically what you were talking about.  I agree, could be useful, but its not core.

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, if there was a standard for this, there might be good benefit to such an implementation.

If there was an implementation which one could install on a RESTful web server, which, while maybe not as powerful as SQL, could do indexed queries, post index processing of simple non-indexable expressions to qualify records return, and sort, (even if passing this to an SQL database do all the work), one could enable this on a server, and products, like Crystal Reports could be developed to use the standard for a report client.

Going through the web server API layer, could provide a way to enforce restrictions on what database operations could be performed to provide more security than fully opening up database access.  Also, logic could be added to the web service to audit and do processing on events resulting from the CRUD operations (essentially triggers).  Yes, database products supply security policies, triggers, and stored procedures to do these things, but with the product we are discussing, one could do it more easily in ruby, than using the database functions.

One could also have pseudo data, which is calculated from ruby code but acts like database records, along side the general DB RESTful access.  Sure, databases can do this which store procedures, and some support writing stored procedures in Java, but this would be better because it would be easier to implement and could be written in ruby.